# HazelcastOSGiInstance deactivate method: synchronous or asynchronous

Tags: java, junit, osgi, hazelcast

I just need to know if the default Java implementation of the `deactivate` method for a `HazelcastOSGiInstance` is synchronous or asynchronous. I had a build fail because of an assert in the jUnit test.

Answer (score 0):

As per the HazelcastOSGiServiceImpl the method deactivate() is synchronized at object level.

See this :- [HazelcastOSGiServiceImpl.java](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/master/hazelcast/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/osgi/impl/HazelcastOSGiServiceImpl.java)

Comment: I'm not worried about it being thread-safe. I'm wondering if it could return prior to the node actually being deactivated.